# how to relate every layout with the image of the same size

Tags: android, image, android-studio

For example : when we use the dimens folder for a texte size value , we go the dimen ( small ) to change the texte size for the small layout(screen) .
So i want to do the same think for images i want to relate hdpi image size(exp) with the appropriate layout-(size: small or big etc)

i think maybe the problem is here because it contain some lines about Title and the full screen
this is the Splash code :

```
package com.medanis.fneclis

import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewConfiguration
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.MediaController
import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifDrawable
import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageButton

class Splash : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //hiding title bar of this activity
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        //making this activity full screen
       window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        //2.63second splash time
        Handler().postDelayed({
            //start main activity
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            //finish this activity
            finish()
        },2630)


        val gib = GifImageButton(this)
        setContentView(gib)
        gib.setImageResource(R.drawable.fneclis_splash_bg)
        val mc = MediaController(this)
        mc.setMediaPlayer(gib.drawable as GifDrawable)
        mc.setAnchorView(gib)
        gib.setOnClickListener(object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                mc.show()
            }

            override fun onClick(p0: DialogInterface?, p1: Int) {
                mc.show()
            }

        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THanks everyone ,i just tried to remove this part of the code and it's work fine. Thank you again ^_^

```
    val gib = GifImageButton(this)
    setContentView(gib)
    gib.setImageResource(R.drawable.fneclis_splash_bg)
    val mc = MediaController(this)
    mc.setMediaPlayer(gib.drawable as GifDrawable)
    mc.setAnchorView(gib)
    gib.setOnClickListener(object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            mc.show()
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: DialogInterface?, p1: Int) {
            mc.show()
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way is completely described in following link.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: i did not understand how that help me please tell me what change must i do ?

Comment: Please check my code i think the problem is maybe there

Answer (score 0):

You have to create different folder for different size of screens

```
drawable-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi        
drawable-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi  

drawable-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi     
drawable-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi   

drawable-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi    
drawable-xxxhdpi           5.5" 1440x2560 xxxhdpi  

drawable-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi     
drawable-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

drawable-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi    
drawable-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi        

drawable-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi        

drawable-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi    
drawable-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
drawable-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

And then put the images for same size in same folder.

Comment: is there any way to relate directly the small layout with the ldpi images

Comment: Android will automatically select appropriate folder. So you have nothing to do.

Comment: that true and it's working good with the others layout but with the splash page wich contain the gif image when i use it in the 10" sceen it choose he smallest image and use it

Comment: Then you ca make a separate folder as your 10" screen dpi.

Comment: how must i called ?

Comment: Please check my code i think the problem is maybe there

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, go to android res directory, create drawable-XXX directories for each resolution, as following

```
/root
   |
    -/res
       |
       /drawable-ldpi
                   |
                   /sample_image.png
       /drawable-mdpi
                   |
                   /sample_image.png
```

and so forth.

create sample_image.png with different resolutions and put them with the same name and different resolutions in corresponding directory.

refer to it in your code only by it's reference in xml file like @drawable/sample_image and in your code by R.drawable.sample_image

Os itself will determine to use which directory based on device screen resolution

Comment: the problem is here gib.setImageResource(R.drawable.fneclis_splash_bg) this code takes only one image size

Comment: No, It take's image id, the image id is unique, it get generated from resource file name, then OS make decision from which directory load the image, the programmer is not involved for choosing different image size from different folder. just separate your files in different directories and use the same id. don't worry, which file would be used is the task of executor ;)